# OpenX Market Advertiser Console API

Tags: openx

I want to develop a simple API for openx advertising console which will allow me to add placements and domains in a placement automatically i.e. I can multiple domains in a placement  simultaneously. 
I am looking for sample code/script to do this??
As I am new to openX please tell me how to do this or provide sample code/script?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply but to do so please access their developer api examples located [here](https://developer.openx.org/wiki/display/API/OpenX+API+Tutorial+%28v1%29)